# How to add new where condition in IQueryable when selecting a view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am fairly new to C# and .Net, so apologies if something doesn't make sense, I will try my best to explain my problem.

I have two methods which are basically going to use the similar query but with slight differences. So instead of repeating the query in both methods I created a third private method which will return the common part of the query and then the functions can add more clauses in query as they require.

Here is a generic function which returns the `IQueryable` object with common part of the query

```
private IQueryable<OfferViewModel> GetOffersQueryForSeller(int sellerId)
{
    return Db.Offers
        .Where(o => o.Sku.SellerId == sellerId && o.IsActive && !o.IsDiscontinued)
        .Select(o => new OfferViewModel
        {
            Id = o.Id,
            Name = o.Sku.Name,
            ImageUrl = o.Sku.ImageUrl ?? o.Sku.Upcq.Upc.ImageUrl,
            QuantityName = o.Sku.QuantityName
        });
}
```

Following are the two method which are reusing the `IQueryable` object

```
public async Task<List<OfferViewModel>> GetSellerOffers(int sellerId)
{
    var query = GetOffersQueryForSeller(sellerId);
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<List<OfferViewModel>> GetDowngradableSellerOffers(int sellerId)
{
    var query = GetOffersQueryForSeller(sellerId);
    return await query
        .Where(o => o.Sku.Id == monthlySkuId)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Now `GetSellerOffers` works just fine but `GetDowngradableSellerOffers` throws a run time error with message `The specified type member 'Sku' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`. I asked around and one of the guys told me that I cannot add additional `where` after adding a `select` which uses a `ViewModel` because then my records will be mapped to `ViewModel` and `LINQ` will attempt to look up props of `ViewModel` instead of database columns.

Now I have two questions,

1. In the docs I read Entity Framework will only run query when I try to fetch the results with methods like `ToList` and if I haven't done that why it wouldn't allow me to apply conditions on database fields/
2. How can I reuse the common query in my scenario?

Comment: then it won't be an async right? And also I would be filtering the result of database records instead of extending the query

Comment: You *can* use `.Where`, but your `IQueryable` is a `IQueryable<OfferViewModel>` and `OfferViewModel` doesn't contain `.Sku.Id` property, does it? And if it contained it, you never initialized it in your `.Select(o => new OfferViewModel{...})`

Comment: I think it doesn't but the actual database row does, I understand the problem now, how can I resolve it?

Comment: I think best way forward would be to change `GetOffersQueryForSeller` to return an `IQueryable<Offer>` and use [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) or similar for the mapping to the viewmodel, i.e. remove the `Select` clause. At the moment, this method does too much and therefore is hard to reuse. It should only query, not query AND map.

Comment: Either add the `Sku.Id` as a property in your `OfferViewModel` like maybe `SkuId`, or remove the `.Select` from your `GetOffersQueryForSeller` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following code:
(The type `Offer` should be replaced by the type of the Elements that `Db.Offers` holds)

```
private IQueryable<OfferViewModel> GetOffersQueryForSeller(int sellerId, Func<Offer,bool> whereExtension)
{
    return Db.Offers
        .Where(o => ... && whereExtension.Invoke(o))
        .Select(o => new OfferViewModel { ... });
}

private IQueryable<OfferViewModel> GetOffersQueryForSeller(int sellerId)
{
    return GetOffersQueryForSeller(sellerId, (o) => true);
}
```

And then call it in `GetDowngradableSellerOffers` like this:

```
public async Task<List<OfferViewModel>> GetDowngradableSellerOffers(int sellerId)
{
    var query = GetOffersQueryForSeller(sellerId, (o) => o.Sku.Id == monthlySkuId);
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```